# Package not recognized in the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed the package `rorolite` from the `pypi.python.org` website directly i.e.without using pip. I extracted the package in `python3.6\Lib\site-packages`. I am using windows 10. The problem I am facing is when I import this package in my code

```
import rorolite
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/all_study/python/project/roro_Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import rorolite
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rorolite'
```

Due to some problem which I don't know, I cannot install packages using pip.

Comment: Might be easier to post your pip error message & address that than attempt to re-write pip (simulate a rewrite with manual steps)

Answer (score 0):

You extracted it in a wrong way. You have to extract the source archive somewhere else and run `pip install .` in the extracted directory.

After that verify that you have a directory `python3.6\Lib\site-packages\rorolite` and have a file `__init__.py` in it.

Or download a wheel (`*.whl`) file and install it using `pip install rorolite*.whl`.

Answer (score 0):

As phd said already you can install it like that. If you are in a Linux, depending on your version you may be able to use a native command such as yum to install the package.
If pip does not work/is not found, remember that you may need to be on the folder that has pip to run it.

I hope you can make it work soon!

Answer (score 0):

Just using "pip" in the terminal (I'm a Mac user) has never worked for me. Try replacing it with "pip3" instead.